# Implementing Refresh Tokens in API

Tags: api, authentication, access-token

Right now my website has an API which is secured using signed key authentication (accessed using a PHP client). Now, I want to introduce the use of a JavaScript client for use with certain endpoints.

What I've done is require the client to authenticate through the PHP client and receive an access token and a refresh token. Then it is able to pass that token to the javascript client and can access endpoints from there.

Now, what I've having a problem with is refreshing the access token when it expires. Is there a way I can accomplish this without requiring the client to use the PHP client again?

The reason I don't want to use the PHP client is because the app using the api is written entirely in javascript, so using the php client would require the page to be redirected, losing the app's state.

I don't want to use OAuth because I don't want the user to have to grant access to the client. I own both the client and api and there will never be any 3rd party clients created.